# Turn off Macbook Pro Display When Using External Display, But Keep Lid Open

Tags: macbook-pro, external-display

How can I turn off the display of a Macbook Pro when using an external display but keep the lid open?

Answer (score 1):

Found some instructions via google. http://installingcats.com/2008/05/12/turn-off-macbook-pro-display-when-using-dvi-to-video-adapter/